# Saved image not found by MediaStore

Tags: android, bitmap, mediastore

I have converted a ScrollView into a Bitmap image and saved it into external storage. A Toast pops up either saying that the image has been successfully saved or it hasn't.

```
    Bitmap bmp = screenShot();
    Bitmap b = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    String fileName = "story.png";
    // create a File object for the parent directory
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Stories/");
    // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    // create a File object for the output file
    File outputFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory, fileName);
    //now attach OutputStream to the file object, instead of a String representation
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try 
    {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), b, "Screen", "screen");

        CharSequence text = "Story saved in file Stories";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        CharSequence text = "Could not save story";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        CharSequence text = "Could not save story";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
```

The Toast pops up saying that the PNG image has been successfully saved. However when I go to view it in the Gallery and I get the following errors.

```
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833): Failed to insert image
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:611)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:922)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:669)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:645)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:902)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at com.example.letswrite.EndScreen.saveToDevice(EndScreen.java:128)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-08 02:22:02.597: E/MediaStore(6833):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there something I can do about this? Is it possible that I am getting these errors because I am using an Android emulator?

Comment: Check the return value of insertImage() as the documentation states `Returns The URL to the newly created image, or null if the image failed to be stored for any reason.` In the LogCat I see: `openAssetFileDescriptor` .That looks suspicious. You are not only trying to let the MediaStore save a Bitmap to file but also just before save that Bitmap to external files dir. You did not tell that.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to Android and I followed some code I found on the internet on how to save a Bitmap file, now that you point it out it does seem like I'm trying to save it to two places at once. I've removed insertImage() as it was returning null and the errors have disappeared but when I go into the gallery it can't find any media.

Comment: Well the gallery will show a lot of pictures i think. All the pictures you took with the device. But it will not show your last saved bitmap. Is that the complaint? Every time you save a picture then you have to call the MediaScanner on that file in order that it shows up in other applications. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-mediascanner/hot But take a file explorer app and you will find your picture story.png in the Stories directory.

Comment: `outputFile.getAbsolutePath()` will tell you where the png is stored.